# Pass a link as a paremeter to g:render tag in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a grails render tag that renders a small chunk of HTML.  Sometimes the HTMl needs to display some text, and sometimes some text and a link.

This chunk of code is working fine:

```
                <g:render template='accountInfo' model="[
                        'accountStatus':subscription.status,
                        'subscription':subscription.plan.name,
                        'msg':g.message (code: 'stripe.plan.info', args:'${[periodStatus, endDate]}')]"/>
```

But I want to be able to pass in some HTML for the 'msg' variable in the model, like this to ouput some text and a link:

```
                <g:render template='accountInfo' model="[
                        'accountStatus':profile.profileState,
                        'subscription':'None selected yet',
                        'msg':<a href="${createLink(controller: 'charge', action: 'basicPlanList')}" title="Start your Subscription">Your profile is currently inactive, select a plan now to publish your profile.</a>]"/>
```

That code does not work.  I've tried adding the link to a taglib, but I can't figure out how to pass the taglib to the 'msg' either:

```
                <g:render template='accountInfo' model="[
                        'accountStatus':profile.profileState,
                        'subscription':'None selected yet',
                        'msg':<abc:showThatLink/>]"/>
```

I am open to suggestions on how best to achieve passing in text only, and text and a grails createLink closure along with some text for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1 Use quotes:

```
<g:render template='accountInfo' model='${ [msg: "<a href='www.someurl.com'>.. </a>"]}' />
```

2 Use another variable:

```
<g:set var="myMsg>
  <a href="www.someurl.com>...</a>
</g:set>`
<g:render template='accountInfo' model='[ 'msg': ${myMsg} ]'/>
```

3 Use the body content of `<g:render />`:

```
<g:render template="accountInfo" model="[ .. ]">
  <a href="..">..</a>
</g:render>
```

You can use to `body()` method inside the template (`accountInfo`) to render the body content. Some time ago I wrote a [small blog post about this](http://www.mscharhag.com/2013/09/grails-using-templates-instead-of.html) which gives some more details.

Comment: #2 worked but I had to remove the closure for the msg to get it to run:  'msg':myMsg